# How do I save a new workbook in Python using xlwing while it gives traceback error

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a simple code to create a new book and then after I want to fill it with data, but `.save`
doesn't work

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book()
wb.save(r'D:\XX\report.xlsx')
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyPython.py", line 5, in <module>
    wb.save(r'D:\XX\report.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1065, in save
    self.impl.save(path, password=password)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 829, in save
    self.xl.SaveAs(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 95, in __call__
    v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 46571, in SaveAs
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
```

Here is my python version: `Python 3.8.0`
XLwings vesrion: `xlwings-0.27.7`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is coming from the path that you give as argument to the function `save()`. You can see that your code works if you save in the folder where your script is running:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book()
wb.save('report.xlsx')
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

If you want to save to specific folder, you can do like this:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book()
wb.save('C:/Users/rcapron/report.xlsx')
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

Please note that I use `/` instead of `\`.